Combining sentences with relative clause
I have a question about combining two sentences with relative clause. Suppose that I have 2 sentences: My son is 35 years old. He has a baby. When I combine them is it a must to write as "My son who has a baby is 35 years old." or can this sentence be as "My son who is 35 years old has a baby."
I know the emphasises and the meanings are different in those sentences, I want to know if it is grammatically correct to combine these sentences in those two ways?
Thanks in advance.

Both versions are perfectly correct. The first might distinguish the 'son who has a baby' from another son who doesn't have children. The second states that he has a baby and inserts the information about his age.


My son who has a baby is 35 years old.


My son who is 35 years old has a baby.

Both versions are grammatical but have different meanings.
Also, both use a defining relative clause, which means the speaker has more than one son.  We can added a pair of bracketing commas to clarify that the speaker has only one son:

My son, who has a baby, is 35 years old.


My son, who is 35 years old, has a baby.

The first version focuses on the age of the son; the second, on the fact that he has a baby.
